# ASPxGridView rows per page

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

How can I set maximum number of rows per page to 5? Default is 10.

```
<SettingsPager PageSize="5">
```

... doesnt work

thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem might appear because you are loading `ASPxGridView` settings from cookies or any other storage where they were saved. Am I right? If so, you should either delete a cookie or set the `SettingsPager.PageSize` within the `Page_LoadComplete` method.

Answer (score 14):

Set [GridView.PageSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize.aspx) to "5"
Try this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"  PageSize="5">

 </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ...  SettingsPager-PageSize="20">
```

Answer (score 3):

I set Number of rows per page to 50 but by Default its 10.

On client side use this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <SettingsPager PageSize="50">
    </SettingsPager>
 </asp:GridView>
```

On server side use

```
SettingsPager.PageSize=50;
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me only when I set it programmaticaly in codeBehind on PageLoad.

Comment: I recommend contacting the DevExpress support team:http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=Question

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have any skin set for the grid view or any other user control attached to the grid view.I faced the same issue  due to the custom export control bind to the grid view.